# fatal error on calling createScaledBitmap() method in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I was trying to draw an image on canvas, but when I call:

```
Bitmap android_guy = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher), 50, 50, true);`
```

I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>     Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference at
>     android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:702)`

I am not calling this method `int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()`.

Can someone explain why it is giving me this error or suggest to me an other way to convert the image to a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher),50,50, true);
```

if `getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)` generates an error try `context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)`

Comment: let me try this

Comment: @Fahad compile time or runtime?

Comment: try this `Bitmap  bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)).getBitmap();
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50,50, true);`